# Help with jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin please

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am having some trouble with a jQuery plugin for multiple uploads.

I am using this plug in http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload

I have followed all his instructions and got it to work locally however for some reason it does not show the multiple attachments remotely.

Is there something I may have missed?

This is my code:

```
<input type="file" name="myfiles[]"  class="multi" />
```

And I have his jQuery .js sheets attached.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting some js error when the site runs remotely?

Comment: No js errors or anything. Basically the bahaviour remotely is as if it was still a single file upload (pathway appearing in the upload area). When done locally the attachments add underneath like on the site. I have been pulling my hair out over this for hours and hours.

Comment: I managed to get the attachments to show on the form remotely however they are not attaching to the mail when sent. I am using PHP Mailer for the backend. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

use http://swfupload.org/, but it's not jQuery plugin.